# Fixed: Python NameError, fixed AttributeError and got this?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, nameerror, attributeerror

FIXED: turns out there is a module already called parser. Renamed it and its working fine! Thanks all.

I got a python NameError I can't figure out, got it after AttributeError. I've tried what I know, can't come up with anything.

main.py:

```
from random import *
from xml.dom import minidom
import parser
from parser import *
print("+---+ Roleplay Stat Reader +---+")
print("Load previous DAT file, or create new one (new/load file)")
IN=input()
splt = IN.split(' ')
if splt[0]=="new":
    xmlwrite(splt[1])
else:
    if len(splt[1])<2:
        print("err")
    else:
        xmlread(splt[1])
ex=input("Press ENTER to Exit...")
```

parser.py:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from random import *
def xmlread(doc):
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(doc)
    itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('item')
    for s in itemlist:
            print(s.attributes['name'].value,":",s.attributes['value'].value)

def xmlwrite(doc):
    print("no")
```

And no matter what I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\Python Programs\Stat Reader\main.py", line 10, in <module>
    xmlwrite.xmlwrite(splt[1])
NameError: name 'xmlread' is not defined
```

The same error occurs when trying to access xmlwrite.

When I change xmlread and xmlwrite to parser.xmlread and parser.xmlwrite I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "K:\Python Programs\Stat Reader\main.py", line 15, in <module>
    parser.xmlread(splt[1])
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'xmlread'
```

The drive is K:\ because it's my personal drive at my school.

Comment: I would go into the interpreter, import parser, dir(parser), and see if you are importing the right module or if it is importing the std-lib parser module.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is really called parser.xml, that's your problem. [It needs to be parser.py in order to work](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html).

EDIT: Okay, since that wasn't your issue, it looks like you have a namespacing issue. You import your parser module twice when you use `import parser` and then `from parser import *`. The first form of it makes "parser" the namespace and the second form directly imports it, so in theory, you should have both `parser.xmlwrite` and `xmlwrite` in scope. It's also clearly not useful to import minidom in main.py since you don't use any minidom functionality in there.

If you clear up those and still have the issue, I would [suggest looking at __ init __.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for). If that still does nothing, it could just plain be a conflict with [Python's parser module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/parser.html), you could substitute a name like myxmlparser.

Comment: It's parser.py, it accesses XML files.

Comment: Actually it was simpler. parser is a default package. I renamed it and it worked. But thanks!